# Java Lambda: Quickly check if 0 or 1 result from Filter and map to result variable, using findFirst/ifPresentOrElse

Tags: java

I need to filter a list of `answers` where there is either 0 or 1 result, and quickly return either (1) that result or (2) NULL as the value of my `Double result`.

```
// Should be set to either (1) matching ans.getAnswerNumericVal() or (2) NULL
Double result = answers.stream().filter(ans -> ans.getQuestionId()) == MY_QUESTION_ID)
                                .findFirst().ifPresentOrElse(ans -> ans.getAnswerNumericVal(), 
                                                             () -> null);
```

But this is a syntactically incorrect expression. I don't want to perform logic inside the `ifPresentOrElse`, I want to map it to either a field or NULL.

Or should I use `.findFirst().map(ans -> ...)` ? There may be 0 results, so `map(..)` can throw an NPE.

Comment: `map()` won't throw an NPE unless your lambda does. It won't be invoked on a null object.

Comment: `map()` will be invoked on a null object. `map()` won't be invoked on an empty `Optional`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.findFirst().map(ans -> ...)`.
`map` will never throw a NPE in your context.

From the documentation:

> If a value is present, apply the provided mapping function to it, and if the result is non-null, return an Optional describing the result. Otherwise return an empty Optional.

So you can do:

```
Double result = answers
                .stream()
                .filter(ans -> ans.getQuestionId() == MY_QUESTION_ID)
                .findFirst()
                .map(Answer::getAnswerNumericVal)
                .orElse(null);
```

Comment: That's not a valid method reference.

Comment: Yes, it's not, `ans` is not the name of the class which `ans` references, however, I don't have context to know the name of the class.

Comment: Then take a guess or use the lambda. But this is definitely wrong.

Comment: Why would I take a guess about a class I know nothing about? That makes no sense.
I've seen this logic applied to several other answers where the question doesn't provide context about the Class.

Comment: It makes more sense than posting code that definitely doesn't compile.

Comment: Let's agree to disagree.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the class name is `Answer`.

Comment: Thanks @geneb. Edited the answer so it uses the class name

Answer (score 1):

It's safe to call `map()` on empty streams or optionals. Just do that and then `orElse(null)`:

```
Double result = answers.stream()
        .filter(ans -> ans.getQuestionId() == MY_QUESTION_ID)
        .map(ans -> ans.getAnswerNumericVal())
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(null);
```

I moved the `map()` to the stream to avoid the extra `Optional` instantiation, but either way works.